# Sqoop import getting halted

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to import a table from mysql to HDFS,but it is getting paused here as below:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/movielens --username root --table tutorials_tbl --m 1

16/11/26 10:47:33 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.

16/11/26 10:47:33 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation

16/11/26 10:47:34 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `tutorials_tbl` AS t LIMIT 1

16/11/26 10:47:34 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop

16/11/26 10:47:34 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar

16/11/26 10:47:36 ERROR orm.CompilationManager: Could not rename /tmp/sqoop-training/compile/f150b283edf7b39ed9facc57a781542e/tutorials_tbl.java to /home/training/./tutorials_tbl.java

java.io.IOException: Destination '/home/training/./tutorials_tbl.java' already exists
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:1811)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:229)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:85)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:369)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:455)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)
16/11/26 10:47:36 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-training/compile/f150b283edf7b39ed9facc57a781542e/tutorials_tbl.jar

16/11/26 10:47:36 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.

16/11/26 10:47:36 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct

16/11/26 10:47:36 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.

16/11/26 10:47:36 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)

16/11/26 10:47:36 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of tutorials_tbl
```

This is the last line of the job.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your yarn logs for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop is a Map only job hence following all semantics of MR .

Please delete "/home/training/./tutorials_tbl.java" and rerun your job.

Comment: /./ doesn't even exist